# Running Vulkan application in docker container (Unity3D)

Tags: docker, unity-game-engine, gpu, vulkan

i need some help running a vulkan app in docker and i hope someone can help me or at least link me something helpful.
i am pretty new to docker, but i already understand the basics of creating a docker container, how to run it etc. and have also gotten a webserver up and running.

as nonsensicle as it might be, for a uni project i need to run an application made using the unity game engine in a docker container for deployment on a server. the app streams the rendered video feed to a webserver, that displays it. the project uses *unity's high definition render pipeline (hdrp)* which only supports rendering using vulkan on linux. i have successfully made a build of the project for linux and tested it on a linux desktop machine.

so far i have gotten a docker image *running* with the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libglu1 xvfb libxcursor1

WORKDIR /app
COPY build/ /app
COPY entrypoint.sh /app

CMD [ "/bin/bash", "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]
EXPOSE 80
```

it runs, but it has no graphics of course. it says it's using a gpu named "null" by the vendor "unity technologies", which doesn't really matter at this point.

since docker isn't really made for gui applications, i also tried running it using `andrewmackrodt/ubuntu-x11` as the base image, to try and get an xserver, to have *something* at least (even if it is an empty screen or errors with the gpus.
i also read about the nvidia container toolkit, which looks like it supports vulkan. sadly i haven't had any luck getting it running so far. now i don't know if you can render a gameengine with it or if it is only really usable for computational stuff on servers, but it looked pretty promising so far.

any help or pointers on how to run vulkan in docker are appreciated.

thanks in advance,
cheers :)

Comment: Surely you build a server build which is text only

Comment: @BugFinder the sever should be handled normally without graphics, but it has to render the images the show up on the webpage hostet by a webserver. so no, not quite text only i'm afraid.

Comment: No. But its not displaying graphics so it shouldn't matter what graphics it find or not.

Comment: Your best bet is to get the Nvidia container solution working.  I got it working a couple of years ago and things should have gotten better since then.  Also, recent versions of Mesa have a Vulkan software renderer (llvmpipe) but it may not be feature-rich enough for Unity and may be too slow.  But you could try to use llvmpipe for your use case on your Linux desktop before trying to put it in a container.